# Can I plot a phase diagram (P against T) of a mixture if the mole compositions are known?

Tags: states-of-matter, phase-diagram

Is it possible? Or do I have to actually experiment it in a lab?

If it's possible, what data would I need? I'm right now only given the mole percentages and the weight percentages. I do know I can separately look up the critical pressure and temperature of each component. And I can further calculate the critical pressure and temperature of the mixture. But in order to understand the phase behavior, I would have to know shape of the phase envelope for every $P$ and $T$, meaning that I need to know the bubble line point and the dew line point.

Comment: Are you asking about liquid/gas interface, or liquid/solid, eutectics, etc?

Comment: @Floris: I guess the question is about liquid/gas as it refers to the dew and bubble lines.

Comment: I'm specifically asking about liquid/gas phase of a hydrocarbon mixture.

Comment: @SebastianRiese I figured that we can use a combination of Raoult's Law and Dalton's Law with K-factor ($K_i$) to solve for the bubble point and dew point.

Now I just need to know how to find the vapor pressure ($P_{i}^{sat}$) of a pure substance for any given temperature. Antoine equation seems to be useful, but I can't find the antoine-equation constants for Nitrogen and Carbon dioxide.

If I know the $P_{i}^{sat}$, I'll be able to find out the $K_i$ factor for a given pressure.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to a binary system. The information you need to construct *any* phase diagram are the four numbers that define the *tie line*:

1. Pressure $P$
2. Temperature $T$
3. Mol fraction of component 1 in phase 1 ($x_1$)
4. Mol fraction of component 1 in phase 2 ($y_1$)

The usual plots we make are $Pxy$, $Txy$ and $xy$. For the $Pxy$ plot we keep $T$ constant and plot $P$ against $x_1$ and against $y_1$ on the same graph. Similarly for the $Txy$ plot. For the $xy$ graph we (usually)keep $P$ constant and plot $y_1$ against $x_1$.

The $PT$ plot is unusual, as far as I can tell. You could construct it by fixing $x_1$ or $y_1$, but you would get different shapes in each case.